# Orgmode export: how to prevent a new line for comment lines

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Currently my orgmode (v8.3.4), when exporting to LaTeX (and maybe other formats but I haven't checked), generates a new line for a comment line or a block of consecutive comment lines. This is undesirable because in LaTeX, that will create a new paragraph. When I write, I often need to comment a line or two in the middle of a paragraph but don't want to split that paragraph into two. Currently, because of this behavior of orgmode, I have to move those commented lines to after the paragraph, which may be confusing when I revise the text.

Below is a minimal example. The orgmode source is:

```
First sentence.
# Commented sentence.
Last sentence.
```

which is exported to LaTeX by orgmode as (omitting the preamble):

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

First sentence.

Last sentence.
\end{document}
```

There is an empty line between the first and last sentences, which results in two paragraphs instead of one.

Is there any way to stop this behavior of orgmode? A comment line, or a block of comment lines, should be exported to 0 byte / character, not even a new line. This is the behavior of LaTeX when processing comments.

Comment: I guess this is a bug in org-mode. It may be worth discussing this on [the org-mode mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode).

Comment: As one of the main org mode devs, Nicolas Goaziou confirmed, [this behavior is expected, not a bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2016-08/msg00276.html).

Comment: both of the above solutions work for `# comments`, but unfortunately none works for #+BEGIN_COMMENT comments #+END_COMMENT a new line is inserted in the LaTeX export in the place where the block comment was present... is there any easy way to fix that? EDIT (hell-yeah, there is): Based on the answer provided by @John, the following works for both the `# comments` and for the `#+BEGIN_COMMENT` blocks: (defun delete-org-comments (backend) (loop for comment in (reverse (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'comment 'identity)) do (setf (buffer-substring (org-element-property :begin comment)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this. Put this code block in your document, and run it. The LaTeX will be in a buffer *Org LATEX Export*.

```
* build :noexport:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun delete-org-comments (backend)
  (loop for comment in (reverse (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer)
                    'comment 'identity))
    do
    (setf (buffer-substring (org-element-property :begin comment)
                (org-element-property :end comment))
          "")))

(let ((org-export-before-processing-hook '(delete-org-comments)))
  (switch-to-buffer (org-latex-export-as-latex)))
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on John's answer, here's an alternative function that uses `org-element-extract-element` and `org-element-interpret-data`:

```
(defun delete-org-comments (backend)
  (let ((tree (org-element-parse-buffer)))
    (org-element-map tree 'comment #'org-element-extract-element)
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert (org-element-interpret-data tree))))
```

The `org-element` API isn't particularly obvious, but it is powerful--you just have to explore it a bit on your own.  :)  Of course, John's is probably faster for large documents since it just modifies the buffer instead of re-interpreting the tree into a string.